# Get all files on disk in python

Tags: python, windows, file

im creating script in python that get all files on disk, but no folders only files. Its my code.

```
import hashlib
import os

if os.name != "nt":
    print("Sorry this script works only on Windows!")

path = "C://"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
print(dir_list)
```

Comment: Hi, so what question do you have? Are you stuck on telling files from folders, or on something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example the pathlib library and build something like that:

```
import pathlib

path = "" # add your path here don't forget a \ at the end on windows
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if pathlib.Path(path + i).is_dir() is not True:
         print(i)
```

It iterates through the current directory and checks if its a directory, by creating a Path object from the list entry and then checks on that object if it is a directory.

Comment: Let me show you what i want again: 
folder -> file.txt -> folder->anotherfile.txt
i want to get all files file.txt and anotherfile.txt